# Разметка элементов в Android приложении

Tags: android, android-layout

На первый взгляд простейшая задача - нарисовать калькулятор в таком стиле:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И первое, что приходит на ум - использовать GridLayout для размещения кнопок. Этот макет позволяет объединять ячейки как по горизонтали, так и по вертикали, что требуется для кнопок "0" и "=".

После первого наброска для меня, как для новичка в этом деле, получился неожиданный результат. Мог бы выложить скрины, но не позволяет репутация. Смысл в том, что на экранах до 7-ми дюймов кнопки просто не помещаются в экран и крайний столбец элементов просто недоступен.

Оказывается GridLayout подгоняет ширину ячеек под самый широкий элемент в строке. Хотя я вначале думал, что грид работает по-другому - подгоняет элементы под размер экрана (как LinearLayout). В итоге вся борьба с гридом сводится к тому, что нужно задавать фиксированные размеры кнопок, чтобы они поместились в экран. Но это, как я понимаю, не выход, так как под каждый размер экрана делать макет - это чушь.

Далее возникла мысль использовать TableLayout. С ним всё прекрасно получается, так как у этого контейнера есть нужный в данной ситуации атрибут shrinkColumns, который позволяет переносить текст, если тот не помещается в ширину колонки. В случае с кнопками, он их ужимает до нужного размера и они все прекрасно смотрятся на любом экране. Но, здесь опять я встретился с траблой. При чем для меня непонятной до сих пор. Ячейки в TableLayout можно объединять только по горизонтали! С чем связано это ограничение - ума не приложу... В итоге кнопку "=" вставить в таблицу как в задании - невозможно.

В итоге, я так пока и не пришел к разумному решению - как правильно сделать разметку кнопок, чтобы они корректно подстраивались под любой экран. Прошу вашей помощи. Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Вот [ссылка на хабр](https://habrahabr.ru/post/191842/), со статьей, там описывается как сделать лайаут, который подойдет для этой задачи.

Answer (score 1):

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp">
        <TableRow>
            <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:weightSum="5">
            <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_span="2" />
            <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

С кнопкой `=` сложнее. `TableLayout` не позволяет объединять строки.

Comment: Я об этом написал в вопросе: "Ячейки в TableLayout можно объединять только по горизонтали! С чем связано это ограничение - ума не приложу... В итоге кнопку "=" вставить в таблицу как в задании - невозможно."
В принципе, ответ я уже получил. Это всё можно выполнить несколькими LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

`GridLayout` позволяет при необходимости растянуть на несколько столбцов или строк. Можно применять следующие атрибуты:

- `android:layout_columnSpan`: количество столбцов, на которые
  растягивается элемент
- `android:layout_rowSpan`: количество строк, на
  которые растягивается элемент.

  ```
  <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:rowCount="3"
  android:columnCount="3">

  <Button
      android:text="1"
      android:layout_column="0"
      android:layout_row="0" />
  <Button android:text="2"
      android:layout_column="1"
      android:layout_row="0"/>
  <Button android:text="3"
      android:layout_column="2"
      android:layout_row="0"  />
  <Button android:text="4"
      android:layout_width="180dp"
      android:layout_columnSpan="2"/>
  <Button android:text="5"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:layout_rowSpan="2"/>
  <Button android:text="6" />
  <Button android:text="7"/>
  ```